# Fedora 37 reboot after update - Grub Out of Range Pointer and not able to rescue boot w/ USB

Tags: fedora, boot, usb, grub2, uefi

After a regular Fedora 37 update last evening, I rebooted my home server (actually a Fedora Workstation 37 but with lots of extras). I went to log in this morning remotely and ... no connection. Upon checking the machine directly, it was giving a Grub Out of Range pointer error on the screen.

Hours of internet searches plus in-article link crawling later, I have concluded this grub issue (https://endeavouros.com/news/full-transparency-on-the-grub-issue/) is the most likely cause. However, I do have a unique situation, I think, and need some help. I am unable to follow the "I have already updated and my machine is broken, what should I do?" instructions for the reason(s) spelled out below, most importantly the inability to even get the USB to boot. I am able to identify the harddrive mount point, and the USB does also show up. But any attempts to insmod linux after setting the key environment variables results in the same out of range error as Grub.

It's an older I5 processor tower (from at least 2009 if not older), and I've never attempted to set up UEFI in the Bios. Attempts to enable UEFI just change the initial error to "No Boot Device available" - I suspect there's a whole list of other challenges I'd have to learn to go that route successfully. So... I'm focusing for now on the Grub related issue. Not only do I get the Grub Out of Range Pointer error from the Grub menu selection, I get it from the command line as well when I attempt to manually (again from the command line) set up and boot to a LiveOS USB or otherwise. I'm stuck for now, not sure what the next step ought to be. I do have physical access to all the hardware, but would prefer a command line solution even if it requires a bit of technical learning on my part.

Answer (score 0):

After wrestling with this for a couple weeks on my system, reinstalling the grub bootloader and rebuild grub.conf fixed the problem on my computer, at least for now anyway.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/bootloading-with-grub2/#restoring-bootloader-using-live-disk